# Callback function in C# doesn't work with Tree Class

Tags: c#, lambda, callback

I have tried to use interface callback function from Class Tree.cs to Form1.cs but it doesn't perform any action at all. Here is my code :

**A function in Tree.cs**

```
public void Print(IOnQuery<T> query,Node<T> node)
{
        if (node == null) node = Top;
        if (node.Left != null)
        {
            Print(query,node.Left);
            query.GetDataItem(node);
        }
        else
        {
            query.GetDataItem(node);
        }

        if (node.Right != null)
        {
            Print(query,node.Right);
        }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IOnQuery<Car>
{

    public void GetDataItem(Node<Car> node)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(node.Item.ToString());
    }

}
```

**My Interface Class**

```
public interface IOnQuery<T>
{
     void GetDataItem(Node<T> node);
}
```

Comment: How did you call `Print` in tree? Show your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `Print` to happen every time GetDataItem is called, you can use events.

In `Form1`, create an event like this, with the parameters `IOnQuery<T> query` and `Node<T> node`.

```
public event Action<IOnQuery<T>, Node<T>> OnDataItemGet;
```

Then you'll need to subscribe to the query with code like:

```
OnDataItemGet += tree.Print;
```

Where `tree` is your tree object.

Now all you have to do is, make `GetDataItem` fire the event.
You can do this by adding one line to `GetDataItem`:

```
OnDataItemGet?.Invoke(query, node);
```

Comment: I really appreciate it! Thank you so much!